# Get last 3 characters of string

Tags: c#

How can I get only the last 3 character out from a given string?

Example input: `AM0122200204`

Expected result: `204`

Comment: Maybe it was the edits made by @ryanyuyu but I really have no idea why this question is closed? Obviously this answer is helpful as it has 57 upvotes! Whatever happened to changing the toxic culture on this forum: https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/

Comment: @AnthonyGriggs In the future if you disagree with the closure of a question, please either vote to reopen or create a meta question with [meta-tag:specific-question] to discuss.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

Many ways this can be achieved.

Simple approach should be taking `Substring` of an input string.

```
var result = input.Substring(input.Length - 3);
```

Another approach using `Regular Expression` to extract last 3 characters.

```
var result = Regex.Match(input,@"(.{3})\s*$");
```

Working [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DtajMx)

Comment: Down voters, please comment. Answer can be improved based on your feedback.

Comment: True Ian, we can improve the answers if they provide comments/feedback. Down voting without reason will not help anyone.

Comment: I guess one really important thing missing from this answer is that it is not a general solution. If the input string may be less than 3 characters long, the call to Substring() will throw.

Answer (score 27):

The easiest way would be using `Substring`

```
string str = "AM0122200204";
string substr = str.Substring(str.Length - 3);
```

Using the overload with one `int` as I put would get the `substring` of a `string`, starting from the index `int`. In your case being `str.Length - 3`, since you want to get the last three chars.

Comment: thanks for answering, but by using the method you proposed, the result shown is AM204 instead of 204.

Comment: @calvinern that's impossible if the `string` is really `AM0122200204`. Please check again.

Comment: That also impossible in any case.

Comment: @calvinern Show your actual code. Taking the last three characters of `AM0122200204` using substring does *not* produce `AM204`.

Comment: Why is the `downvote` here? If the question is bad, the question should be downvoted and if the answer is bad, the answer should be downvoted. What is this downvote?

Comment: @Ian some users downvote answers to questions they downvote.  The reasoning is that they are trying to discourage answers to questions they deem are lazy or otherwise poorly formed.  Just a possibility.

Comment: ok, i know whats wrong, thanks for all the help and sassistance.

Answer (score 22):

From C# 8 [Indices and ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#indices-and-ranges)

Last 3 digits of "AM0122200204" string:

```
"AM0122200204"[^3..]
```

Comment: This is the way.

Answer (score 2):

Many years lates..but here is my go at it. There are some here that accept smaller sizes and others that do not. The examples below show the output for all. I also added some benchmarks.net timings for the longer example.

```
string longgText = "this is some text in a string"; 
string shortText = "hi"; 
string result;

/*                Function                                 Result           Time/Source*/
/***************************************************************************************/
result = longgText.Substring(Math.Max(0,longgText.Length-6));//"string"        9.6 ns
result = shortText.Substring(Math.Max(0,shortText.Length-6));//"hi             Sunsetquest

result = longgText[^(Math.Min(6, longgText.Length))..];    // "string"         9.9 ns 
result = shortText[^(Math.Min(6, shortText.Length))..];    // "hi"             Sunsetquest

result = longgText.PadLeft(6)[^6..];                       // "string"         12.7 ns
result = shortText.PadLeft(6)[^6..];                       // "    hi"         

result = longgText[^6..];                                  // "string"         9.0 ns
result = shortText[^6..];                                  // [Exception]      Visual Sharp

result=longgText.AsSpan().Slice(longgText.Length-6).ToString();//"string"      13.0 ns
result=shortText.AsSpan().Slice(shortText.Length-6).ToString();//[Exception]   Lemon Sky

result = longgText.Substring(longgText.Length - 6);        // "string"         8.8 ns
result = shortText.Substring(shortText.Length - 6);        // [Exception]      Ian

result = Regex.Match(longgText, @"(.{6})\s*$").ToString(); // "string"         3600 ns 
result = Regex.Match(shortText, @"(.{6})\s*$").ToString(); // ""               Hari Prasad
```

Answer (score 1):

With the introduction of `Span`s in C# 7.3 and .NET Core 2.1 we now have an additional way of implementing this task without additional memory allocations. The code would look as follows:

```
var input = "AM0122200204";

var result = input
    .AsSpan()
    .Slice(input.Length - 3);
```

In traditional code, every string manipulation creates a new string on the heap. When doing heavy string-based manipulations like in compilers or parsers, this can quickly become a bottleneck.

In the code above, `.AsSpan()` creates a safe, array-like structure pointing to the desired memory region inside the original string. The resulting `ReadOnlySpan` is accepted by many method overloads in libraries.

For example, we can parse the last 3 digits using `int.Parse`:

```
int value = int.Parse(result)
```

Answer (score -3):

```
let newString = oldString.slice(-3)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This looks like JavaScript, not C#.