# Get Last Four word after splitting a string

Tags: c#, .net

I have two string like below

```
var str1 = '20180215.20150215.3.1.0.0';
var str2 = '20180215.3.1.0.0';
```

I need to get the last four word after splitting these string with .

```
var str1Arr = str1.split('.')
```

What i need is a generic method to get last four words 3.1.0.0.

Thanks

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35691375/get-last-3-characters-of-string

Comment: @silambarasanvediappan i think you have not read the question carefully i know how to get last three characters from a string but in my case i have a requirement to split things and then get the last 4 words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static class SplitExtension
{
    public static string LastNItems(this string str, int nItem, char separator = '.')
    {
        return string.Join(separator.ToString(), str.Split(separator).Reverse().Take(nItem).Reverse());
    }

    public static string[] LastNItems(this string[] strArray, int nItem)
    {
        return strArray.Reverse().Take(nItem).Reverse().ToArray();
    }
}
```

This will enable you to do

```
var str1 = "20180215.20150215.3.1.0.0";

var str1Last4 = str1.LastNItems(4); // "3.1.0.0"
var str1Last4Items = str1.Split('.').LastNItems(4); // ["3","1","0","0"]
```

or for completion

```
var str1Last4Items = str1.LastNItems(4).Split('.'); // ["3","1","0","0"]
```

Comment: My idea is copied. :/

Comment: Sorry, I did use the same naming but not the same content. @SiyavashHamdi

Answer (score 7):

`var lastFour = str1Arr.Reverse().Take(4).Reverse().ToArray();`

Answer (score 1):

You can use it by extension methods.

```
public static class CommonExtension
{
    public static List<string> LastNItem(this string str, int nItem, string separator = ".")
    {
        var splittedWords = str.Split(new [] { separator }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        var res = splittedWords.Reverse().Take(nItem).Reverse().ToList();

        return res;
    }
}
```

Then you can call it everywhere you want.

```
var str1 = "1.0.0";
var str2 = "20180215.3.1.0.0";

var str1Last4 = str1.LastNItem(4);
var str2Last4 = str2.LastNItem(4);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just `Skip` top `Length - 4` items?

```
string str1 = "20180215.20150215.3.1.0.0";

string[] str1Arr = str1.Split('.');

var result = str1Arr
  .Skip(str1Arr.Length - 4)
  .ToArray(); // if you want an array materialization
```

This code will do even when `str1Arr.Length < 4` (in this case the entire `str1Arr` copy will be returned). In case you want a `string` as the `result` you can just try `Substring` (without creating any arrays)

```
  string str1 = "20180215.20150215.3.1.0.0";
  string result = str1;
  int index = result.Length;

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    index = str1.LastIndexOf('.', index - 1);

    if (index < 0)
      break;
  }

  result = index < 0 ? result : result.Substring(index + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be faster than double reverse answer.

```
var str1 = "20180215.20150215.3.1.0.0";
var str2 = "20180215.3.1.0.0";

var words = str1.Split('.');
var toSkip =  words.Length - 4;
var result = string.Join(".", words.Skip(toSkip));
```

A bit of testing showed that is is just slightly faster than double reverse.

What is 10 times faster than this one?
Well avoiding memory allocations and enumerations will be.

Here are the results of comparing 3 different extension methods for 10M iterations:

double reverse: 6463ms
split + skip: 5269ms
straight: 492ms

```
void Main()
{
    var str1 = "20180215.20150215.3.1.0.0";

    var numIterations = 10000000;

    var timer = new Stopwatch();


    timer.Start();
    for (var i = 0; i < numIterations; i++)
    {
        str1.LastNItemsDoubleReverse(4);
    }
    timer.Stop();
    timer.ElapsedMilliseconds.Dump("double reverse");

    timer.Reset();
    timer.Start();
    for (var i = 0; i < numIterations; i++)
    {
        str1.LastNItemsSplitNSkip(4);
    }
    timer.Stop();
    timer.ElapsedMilliseconds.Dump("split + skip");

    timer.Reset();
    timer.Start();
    for (var i = 0; i < numIterations; i++)
    {
        str1.LastNItemsStraight(4);
    }
    timer.Stop();
    timer.ElapsedMilliseconds.Dump("straight");

}
public static class ext
{
    public static string LastNItemsDoubleReverse(this string str, int nItem, char separator = '.')
    {
        return string.Join(separator.ToString(), str.Split(separator).Reverse().Take(nItem).Reverse());
    }

    public static string LastNItemsSplitNSkip(this string str, int nItem, char separator = '.')
    {

        var words = str.Split(separator);
        var toSkip = words.Length - nItem;
        return string.Join($"{separator}", words.Skip(toSkip));
    }

    public static string LastNItemsStraight(this string str, int nItem, char separator = '.')
    {

        int j=1,i=str.Length-1;
        for (;i>=0 && j<nItem;i--){
            if(str[i]==separator) j++;
        }
        return str.Substring(i);

    }
}
```

Comment: Somebody incorrectly flagged your answer as low-quality. You should add some accompanying text to explain how your answer works to prevent further flagging and/or downvotes. A code-only answer [is not low-quality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358757/1364007). Does it attempt to answer the question? If not, flag as 'not an answer' or recommend deletion (if in the review queue). b) Is it technically incorrect? Downvote or comment. [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/18831031).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string GetLastFour(string str)
{
    string[] arr = str.Split('.');
    System.Text.StringBuilder lastFour = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    if (arr.Length >= 4)
    {
        for (int k = arr.Length - 4; k < arr.Length; k++)
        {
            if (k == arr.Length - 1)
            {
                lastFour.Append(arr[k]);
            }
            else
            {
                lastFour.Append(arr[k] + ".");
            }
        }
    }

    return lastFour.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the following :

```
List<string> GetLastFourWords()
{
   List<string> lastFour = new List<string>();

   try
   {
      string[] arr = str1.split('.');
      for(int i = 3; i >= 0; i-- )
      {
         lastFour.Add(arr[str1.length - 1 - i]);
      }
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
   }

   return lastFour;
}
```

Comment: order will be reversed

Comment: The `try..catch` should be removed.

Comment: and why is that ?