# c# Leave last 3 letters in a string

Tags: c#, string, substring

How to remove letters from the string and leave just 3 last chars

Input:

```
foobar
```

Output:

```
bar
```

I tried:

```
string.Concat("foobar".Reverse().Skip(3).Reverse());
```

But that removes last 3 lines not keeps them

Comment: `string.Concat("hello".Reverse().Take(3).Reverse());`

Comment: This is a duplicate of following:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35691375/get-last-3-characters-of-string

Comment: @stickybit i think yes, this question should be marked as duplicate

Comment: Oh my, please *don't* take the last N chars of a string by creating at least 3 copies of the string by using Linq's Reverse() twice...That's just not a good way to do something better served by `string.Substring()`.

Comment: @stickybit That question has been closed, and is not visible to lower-rep users

Answer (score 8):

Well, you can try `Substring`: if `source` is *long enough* we get `Substring` otherwise leave `source` intact:

```
 string source = ...

 string result = source.Length > 3 
   ? source.Substring(source.Length - 3) 
   : source;
```

Or even

```
 string result = source.Substring(Math.Max(0, source.Length - 3));
```

Comment: that works aswell thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Since C# 8, you can also use [range syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#indices-and-ranges):

```
string result = source.Length > 3 ? source[^3..] : source;
```

or:

```
string result = source[^Math.Min(3, source.Length)..];
```

`[^3..]` is a range which means "start 3 elements from the end, and keep going until the end".

Comment: I love this state of the art code (ranges) ;)

Comment: Out of interest, I looked at the IL generated for this, and it does actually translate it into a call to `string.Substring()` so this is pretty optimal.

Comment: Yeah, it's got special support for arrays and strings, and it fakes indexers which take a range if the type has a suitable `Slice` method, and a `Length` or `Count` property

Answer (score 3):

There is a one line solution as well. Just check whether source string has enough length to get last 3 characters using `Substring` or leave string as is. `Math.Max` function will return a correct index

```cs
var str = "foobar";
var result = str.Substring(Math.Max(0, str.Length - 3));
```